# Finding bifurcation values of one-parameter families of first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

> Consider the following one-parameter families of first-order differential equations defined on the reals:
>   $$ \dot x = \mu - x - e^{-x} $$
>   $$ \dot x = x(\mu + e^x) $$
>   $$ \dot x = x - \frac{\mu x}{1+x^2}$$
>   Determine the critical points and the bifurcation values, plot vector fields on the line, and draw a bifurcation diagram in each case.

I'm having trouble getting started with this problem because in class, we always worked with a system of equations - $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$.  If anyone could give me a technique to go about finding the bifurcation values, etc. - that would work with all three of these equations - that would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do each one individually, and it should be easier than what you've done in class because each of those equations has only one dependent variable.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really know how... Like I found a problem similar to the third equation on this site but I don't really understand the solution.